# Как остановить 2d анимацию на python(модуль tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, 2d, gdi

Мне нужно остановить круги в момент их прикосновения
Честно не знаю как это реализовать
Прошу помощи

```
import math
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk

SIZE = 600
WIDTH = SIZE
HEIGHT = SIZE
RADIUS4 = SIZE / 5
RADIUS1 = SIZE / 2.85
#radius orbiti
RADIUS2 = SIZE / 12
#radius pervogo kruga
RADIUS3 = SIZE / 15
#radius vtorogo kruga

def coords(angle):
    x = math.cos(angle) * RADIUS1
    y = math.sin(angle) * RADIUS1
return x - RADIUS2 + SIZE / 2, y - RADIUS2 + SIZE / 2, x + RADIUS2 + SIZE / 2, y + RADIUS2 + SIZE / 2

def coords_1(angle):
    x = math.cos(angle) * RADIUS4
    y = math.sin(angle) * RADIUS4
return x - RADIUS3 + SIZE / 2, y - RADIUS3 + SIZE / 2, x + RADIUS3 + SIZE / 2, y + RADIUS3 + SIZE / 2

def motion(angle):
    angle = angle + 0.1
    c.coords(f, coords(angle))
    root.after(50, lambda: motion(angle))

def motion_1(angle):
    angle = angle - 0.1
    c.coords(f1, coords_1(angle))
    root.after(50, lambda: motion_1(angle))

angle = 0
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="white")
c.pack()
#c.create_oval(SIZE / 2 - RADIUS1, SIZE / 2 - RADIUS1, SIZE / 2 + RADIUS1, SIZE / 2 + RADIUS1)
# #орбита окружности
#c.create_oval(SIZE / 2 - RADIUS4, SIZE / 2 - RADIUS4, SIZE / 2 + RADIUS4, SIZE / 2 + RADIUS4)
# #орбита окружности 2
c.create_oval(SIZE / 2 - 160, SIZE / 2 - 160, SIZE / 2 + 160, SIZE / 2 + 160)
#орбита окружности 3
f = c.create_oval(coords(angle), fill='black')
f1 = c.create_oval(coords(angle), fill='green')
root.after(100, motion(angle))
root.after(100, motion_1(angle))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Немножко теории, в момент прикосновения 2 окружностей сумма их радиусов равна расстоянию между их центрами. Если я правильно понял то ваши круги двигаются в плоскости, тогда, после каждого движения рассчитывайте растояние между центрами и сравнивайте с суммой радиусов, если это расстояние меньше суммы радиусов, не продолжайте движение

Comment: Спасибо 
А вы не можете подсказать как именно остановить движение 
Не знаю как это прописать

Comment: В тех функциях где у вас осуществляется движение, перед изменением координат пропишите if-statement. Например if distance > radius1 + radius: root.after(...) else: pass